# Django prefetch_related seem to not work as expected

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

## Descirption

There is a `Foo` model that has a ForeignKey field `bar`:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  ...
  bar = models.ManyToManyField('bar.Bar', related_name='some_bar')
  ...
```

Also `Foo` has `get_config()` method which returns its fields including `bar` like:

```
def get_config(self):
  return {
    ...
    'bar': map(lambda x: x.get_config(), self.bar.all())
    ...
```

Now there are 10,000 rows of `Foo` in the database. There are some `Bar` rows as well.

Trying to retrieve the data about 10,000 `Foo` including the nested `Bar` data:

```
query = Foo.objects.all().prefetch_related('bar')
return [obj.get_config() for obj in query]
```

## Problem

The query executes around 6 seconds. If there is no `bar` field - only 400 milliseconds.

The prefetch seems to not work completely `bar.get_config()` seem to hit the database for each iteration step. It is supposed to simply load all `Bar` objects once and get config from that bar-query to populate each `foo` config.

### Thoughts

If use `iterator()` for the `for` loop, the call almost stalls and take dozens of seconds: `[obj.get_config() for obj in query.iterator()]`

Answer (score 0):

The `prefetch_related` is working. Django prefetches `Bar` with a single SELECT containing WHERE clause with `ids` of all `Foo`. This SELECT with 10k ids is much faster than 10k SELECTS, but much slower than single SELECT without any filter.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not tested it, I suspect the bulk of the slowness you see in your query is coming from python, not the DB queries. When using `prefetch_related(...)`, 1 query is made for all Foo and 1 query for all Bar. The results of those queries are then stitched together by Django in Python-land.

Performance they could vary depending on the particulars of your setup (DB engine, indexes, DB host specs, service host specs, etc.). You'll need to do some profiling to drill down and see your bottleneck(s).

---

Regarding behaviour you mention under the "thoughts" heading... Versions of Django <4.1 [ignore `prefetch_related` when using `.iterator()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20if%20you%20use%20iterator()%20to%20run%20the%20query%2C%20prefetch_related()%20calls%20will%20be%20ignored%20since%20these%20two%20optimizations%20do%20not%20make%20sense%20together.).

> Note that if you use iterator() to run the query, prefetch_related() calls will be ignored since these two optimizations do not make sense together.

Support for mixing `prefetch_related` and `iterator` was [added in Django 4.1](https://github.com/django/django/commit/edbf930287cb72e9afab1f7208c24b1146b0c4ec). If you upgrade to Django >=4.1, then you might try using `.iterator()` again. This probably won't improve your total DB time, but it might improve memory usage, and avoid service-host bottlenecks.